# Get bounding rectangle segments of a rotated rectangle (matrix?)

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, rotations

My problem:

I have: **$x$**, **$y$** & **$\alpha$** and the aspect ratio **$o$**(long):**$p$**(short) (red rectangle)

I want to have **$n$** & **$m$** in dependancy of $x, y, \alpha, o, p$

[image: Graphic]

I tried to figure it out with `cos`, `sin` and `tan` but I don't get a solution. My math teacher said something about the `matrix`  of rotation, but I don't know this method.

I'm also fine with the points where the red corners are on the black rectangle.

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Question is unclear. If x and y are the box dimensions then there are lots of rectangles (thinner and wider ones lying in the same direction) that can lie as shown making an angle $\alpha$.

Comment: @Paul X and y are the black box dimensions, n and m are the black lines until the red corners.

Comment: then as I said, your problem cannot be solved uniquely. you can draw lots of red rectangles meeting the left side at an angle $\alpha$

Comment: Yeah i can see it now too. There is no unique answer. Thank you

Comment: @Paul, i've added the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z$ be the length of the hypotenuse of the top left right-angled triangle whose two sides are $m$ and $n$. Then $z$ is the length of one side of the red rectangle. Let the length of the other side be $kz$. If we don't know which side is longer in advance, we don't know whether $k$ is equal to $\frac po$ or $\frac op$. However, we do have
$$
\begin{cases}
z\sin\alpha + kz\cos\alpha = x,\tag{1}\\
z\cos\alpha + kz\sin\alpha = y.
\end{cases}
$$
Hence we can determine $k$ without using $o$ or $p$:
$$
k = \frac{y\sin\alpha - x\cos\alpha}{x\sin\alpha - y\cos\alpha}.\tag{2}
$$
Now, from $(1)$, we get
$$
z = \frac x{\sin\alpha + k\cos\alpha}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
n &= z\sin\alpha = \frac{x\sin\alpha}{\sin\alpha + k\cos\alpha},\\
m &= z\cos\alpha = \frac{x\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha + k\cos\alpha}.
\end{align}
$$